# React navigation 5 deep link not work when nested navigator in react native in android and ios

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5

i have nested stack navigator, first is splash and login stack navigator after that i have bottom tab navigator in which i have five stack navigator like home stack, search stack, help Support, setting stack and profile stack navigator,  and details navigator but  Episode details navigator is outside the (home stack navigator and tab navigator). how can i create config path for that, in normal i just navigation.navigate(details) from home navigator.
my config deep link work when app is open but when app closed its opened the page but don't go back.

```
    xcrun simctl openurl booted bhpsApp://episode/episodedetails/182
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import * as React from 'react'
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import {NavigationContainer, StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import {Image, Text} from 'react-native'
import {RouteKeys, SCREEN_TITLE} from './RouteKeys'
import SplashScreen from '../screens/OnBoardingScreens/SplashScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../screens/AuthenticationScreens/loginScreen'
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeContainer/homeScreen'
import Images from '../assets/AppImages'
import {Colors, Strings, Scaling} from '../constants'
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreens/settingsScreen'
import EdpisodeDetailScreen from '../screens/HomeContainer/edpisodeDetailScreen'
import NotificationsScreen from '../screens/NotificationScreen'
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreens/searchScreen'
import MyProfileScreen from '../screens/MyProfileScreens/myProfileScreen'
import HelpAndSupportScreen from '../screens/ChatScreens/helpAndSupport'
import LocationConatainer from '../common/components/LocationConatainer'
import MapScreen from '../screens/SearchScreens/mapScreen/MapScreen'
import ListViewScreen from '../screens/SearchScreens/listViewScreen/ListViewScreen'
import LocationDetailScreen from '../screens/SearchScreens/locationDetailScreen'
import DrawerModal from '../common/components/DrawerModal'
import {useTheme} from '../screens/Themes'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import {StorageKey} from '../constants/AsyncStorageService'
import AboutUsScreen from '../screens/HomeContainer/aboutUsScreen/AboutUsScreen'
import DonateScreen from '../screens/HomeContainer/donateScreen/DonateScreen'
import ShopStoreScreen from '../screens/HomeContainer/shopStoreScreen/ShopStoreScreen'
import MembershipScreen from '../screens/HomeContainer/membershipScreen/MembershipScreen'
    const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const theme = useTheme()
    
    const LoginProcessNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const LoginProcessScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <LoginProcessNavigator.Navigator>
          <LoginProcessNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.LOGIN}
            component={LoginScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </LoginProcessNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    
    const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const HomeScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (`enter code here`
        <HomeNavigator.Navigator>
          <HomeNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.HOME_SCREEN}
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </HomeNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    
    const AboutUsNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const AboutUsScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <AboutUsNavigator.Navigator>
          <AboutUsNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.ABOUT_US_SCREEN}
            component={AboutUsScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </AboutUsNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const DonateNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const DonateScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <DonateNavigator.Navigator>
          <DonateNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.DONATE_SCREEN}
            component={DonateScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </DonateNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const MembershipNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const MembershipScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <MembershipNavigator.Navigator>
          <MembershipNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.MEMBERSHIP_SCREEN}
            component={MembershipScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </MembershipNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const ShopStoreNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const ShopStoreScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <ShopStoreNavigator.Navigator>
          <ShopStoreNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.SHOP_STORE_SCREEN}
            component={ShopStoreScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </ShopStoreNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const NotificationNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const NotificationScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <NotificationNavigator.Navigator>
          <NotificationNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.NOTIFICATIONS_SCREEN}
            component={NotificationsScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </NotificationNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const EdpisodeDetailNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const EdpisodeDetailScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <EdpisodeDetailNavigator.Navigator>
          <EdpisodeDetailNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.EPISODE_DETAIL_SCREEN}
            component={EdpisodeDetailScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </EdpisodeDetailNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const SearchNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const SearchScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <SearchNavigator.Navigator>
          <SearchNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.SEARCH_SCREEN}
            component={SearchScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          <SearchNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.LOCATION_CONTAINER}
            component={LocationConatainer}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </SearchNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const MapNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const MapScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <MapNavigator.Navigator>
          <MapNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.MAP_SCREEN}
            component={MapScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </MapNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const ListViewNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const ListViewScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <ListViewNavigator.Navigator>
          <ListViewNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.LIST_VIEW_SCREEN}
            component={ListViewScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </ListViewNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const ProfileScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <ProfileNavigator.Navigator>
          <ProfileNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.MY_PROFILE}
            component={MyProfileScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </ProfileNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const HelpAndSupportNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const HelpAndSupportScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <HelpAndSupportNavigator.Navigator>
          <HelpAndSupportNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.HELP_AND_SUPPORT_SCREEN}
            component={HelpAndSupportScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </HelpAndSupportNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    const LocationDetailNavigator = createStackNavigator()
    const LocationDetailScreenNaviagtor = () => {
      return (
        <LocationDetailNavigator.Navigator>
          <LocationDetailNavigator.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.LOCATION_DETAILS_SCREEN}
            component={LocationDetailScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </LocationDetailNavigator.Navigator>
      )
    }
    
    //TAB NAVIGATOR BOTTOM TAB MANUFECTURER
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
    const TabScreenNavigator = () => {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName={RouteKeys.HOME_SCREEN}
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR,
            inactiveTintColor: Colors.WHITE,
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 15,
            },
            style: {
              backgroundColor: theme === 'dark' ? Colors.RED_MAROON : Colors.BLACK,
              height: Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_60,
              borderTopLeftRadius: Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_10,
              borderTopRightRadius: Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_10,
              marginTop: -Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
              borderTopColor: Colors.BLACK,
            },
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen
            //key={RouteKeys.HOME_SCREEN}
            name={RouteKeys.HOME_SCREEN}
            // key={RouteKeys.HOME_SCREEN}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <Image
                  source={Images.homeIcon}
                  style={{
                    height:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    width:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                    tintColor: color,
                  }}
                />
              ),
              tabBarLabel: () => {
                ;<Text></Text>
              },
            }}
            component={HomeScreenNaviagtor}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.SEARCH_SCREEN}
            //key={RouteKeys.SEARCH_SCREEN}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <Image
                  source={Images.searchIcon}
                  style={{
                    height:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_25
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    width:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_25
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                    tintColor: color,
                  }}
                />
              ),
              tabBarLabel: () => {
                ;<Text></Text>
              },
            }}
            component={SearchScreenNaviagtor}
          />
    
          <Tab.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.HELP_AND_SUPPORT_SCREEN}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <Image
                  source={Images.messageIcon}
                  style={{
                    height:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    width:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                    tintColor: color,
                  }}
                />
              ),
              tabBarLabel: () => {
                ;<Text></Text>
              },
            }}
            component={HelpAndSupportScreenNaviagtor}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.SETTINGS_SCREEN}
            // key={RouteKeys.SETTINGS_SCREEN}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <Image
                  source={Images.settingIcon}
                  style={{
                    height:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    width:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                    tintColor: color,
                  }}
                />
              ),
              tabBarLabel: () => {
                ;<Text></Text>
              },
            }}
            component={SettingsScreen}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name={RouteKeys.MY_PROFILE}
            // key={RouteKeys.MY_PROFILE}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <Image
                  source={Images.profileIcon}
                  style={{
                    height:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    width:
                      color === Colors.HERITAGE_COLOR
                        ? Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_28
                        : Scaling.HEIGHT_SCALE_20,
                    resizeMode: 'contain',
                    tintColor: color,
                  }}
                />
              ),
              tabBarLabel: () => {
                ;<Text></Text>
              },
            }}
            component={ProfileScreenNaviagtor}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      )
    }
    
    export const Router = () => {
      const linking = {
        prefixes: ['https://play.google.com/store/apps', 'bhpsApp://'],
        config: {
          SPLASH: 'splash',
          TAB_SCREEN: {
            path: 'tabscreen',
            screens: {
              HOME_SCREEN: {
                path: 'home',        
              },
              SEARCH_SCREEN: {
                path: 'search',
              },
              HELP_AND_SUPPORT_SCREEN: {
                path: 'support',
              },
            },
          },
          EPISODE_DETAILS: 'episode',
          EPISODE_DETAIL_SCREEN: {
            path: 'episodedetails/:episodeId',
            params: {
              episodeId: null,
            },
          },
        },
      
      }
      return (
        <NavigationContainer
          linking={linking}
          fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
          <RootNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName={RouteKeys.SPLASH}>
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.SPLASH}
              component={SplashScreen}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.LOGIN}
              component={LoginProcessScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.TAB_SCREEN}
              component={TabScreenNavigator}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.NOTIFICATIONS_SCREEN}
              component={NotificationScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.EPISODE_DETAILS}
              component={EdpisodeDetailScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.MAP_SCREEN}
              component={MapScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.LIST_VIEW_SCREEN}
              component={ListViewScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.LOCATION_DETAILS_SCREEN}
              component={LocationDetailScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.ABOUT_US_SCREEN}
              component={AboutUsScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.DONATE_SCREEN}
              component={DonateScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.SHOP_STORE_SCREEN}
              component={ShopStoreScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <RootNavigator.Screen
              name={RouteKeys.MEMBERSHIP_SCREEN}
              component={MembershipScreenNaviagtor}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          </RootNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )
    }
```